# What is the expected value of a permutation of the digits of the number $9876$ if $6$ is not in the thousands place?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, expected-value

What is the expected value of a permutation of the digits of the number $9876$ if $6$ is not in the thousands place?

I know that the expected value has to be somewhere in the $8000$s because only $7,8,9$ are allowed in the thousands digit, but I'm not sure how to determine the rest.
I could just sum up all the possible combinations since there are only $18$, but that feels way too tedious. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you think that summing all of the digit permutation values, and then subtracting those with a $6$ in the thousands place, would be less tedious?

Comment: @JohnOmielan probably, but how would I sum all of the digit permutation values?

Comment: Consider that $9876 = 9(1000) + 8(100) + 7(10) + 6$ and then determine the sum of the digit permutations for each separate digit (note that the sum will be the same for each one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that you can easily sum up the possible numbers.

Of all the possible numbers (which is 18 in total), 6 $(3!)$ of them will have 6 in one's position, and 7, 8, and 9 will occur in one's position for 4 ($\frac{18-6}{3}$) numbers each.

Summing one's position, we get, $6*6 + (7+8+9)*4 = 36 + 24*4 = 36+96 = 132$.
Therefore, 2 will be in the one's position in the answer, 13 goes to carry. You get the idea?

My answer came out to be $158652/18 = 8814$.

Comment: I think you mean the answer is $158652/18=8814$, but thanks so much for the explanation! Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @mathdummy yes, actually by answer I meant the sum only. You're welcome, I'm glad to help.